# Google calendar- get modified events with nextSyncToken via API rest

Tags: python, rest, curl, google-calendar-api

Can anyone please tell me how to write a cURL to get events (only modified) list with nextSyncToken?
This is my code that's not working:

```
def get_headers():
    headers = {
        #'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Authorization': access_token_json
    }
    return headers

def get_nexttokensync_list_event():
    url_get_list_event = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/id@gmail.com/events"
    querystring = {"nextSyncToken": "CMCEh************jd4CGAU="}
    response = requests.request("GET", url_get_list_event, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    json_event_list_formatted = response.text
    print(json_event_list_formatted)
```

Comment: Yes, i've done it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i've done it!
Here is my code:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/here_calendar_id/events"

querystring = {"syncToken":"here_token"}

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```